# Accessing Hudson Script Console from the command line

Tags: hudson

Pretty self explanitory this one.

As described here: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Hudson+Script+Console you can access the Groovy script console from the Hudson web interface. I want to be able to access this from a shell so I can execute Groovy scripts from a terminal etc...

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe this depends on whether the plugin adds custom CLI commands that can be used by Hudson CLI.

Comment: Take a step back - how do I access a Hudson CLI?

Comment: I presume this is what you are refering to? `java -jar hudson-cli.jar -s http://server:8080/ help`

Answer (score 0):

Download http://server/jnlpJars/hudson-cli.jar

Use `java -jar hudson-cli.jar -s http://server:8080/ groovysh` for interactive groovy, `java -jar hudson-cli.jar -s http://server:8080/ groovy` to run a script.

Comment: Looks like this is slightly different to the script console on Hudson itself as I am getting an import error for hudson.scm.SubversionSCM which is presumably loaded via a plugin mechanism and hence this class is not currently in my classpath...